# Nuxt 3 - HMR only works on app.vue, but not on /pages etc

Tags: vue.js, vite, nuxt3, vscode-devcontainer, hmr

When working on a Nuxt3-Project with a Dev-Container in VS-Code HMR doesn't work as it should.

If I change something in my app.vue in the root folder everything works fine: HMR works as expected. But changes in other folders don't. For example: if I change something on a Vue-File in my pages-directory there is no effect. I have to restart my app to see the changes.

Is there maybe some additional configuration?

When I work on Windows, without DevContainer everything works fine.